# How to enable mark occurrences feature for the OpenEdge editor

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I've been missing this feature since starting to work with OpenEdge, and I am left wondering if the is any way to enable this.

I've checked the OpenEdge editor properties in Eclipse but was unable to find the option to toggle this. Is there a plugin that can enable it? Maybe a hidden way to do that without the need of a plugin? Any help is appreciated.
[Mark occurrences feature example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mgvf.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you search using Ctrl+H (or Search -> Search) in the OpenEdge Editor (Eclipse based) you get marked occurences in the editor as well as a list of all search hits in the Search tab.

In this example I've searched for "RETURNS CHARACTER"

In the old AppBuilder editor you are out of luck.

[image]

Comment: Is not ideal... But you can use Code Preview (F5) with Control+F in the classic App Builder. Pressing F9 you place you at the next occurance. Off course this is only possible at one program at a time.